# Return last 10 objects of array in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array:

```js
myArr= [
  {"name":"John", "schedule": [{"course":"ESL", "hours": 25},{"course": "Math", "hours": 50},{"course": "History", "hours": 75}]},
  {"name":"Julia", "schedule": [{"course":"English", "hours": 20},{"course": "Geography", "hours": 35},{"course": "Math", "hours": 55}]},
  {"name":"Adam", "schedule": [{"course":"Physics", "hours": 15},{"course": "Math", "hours": 50},{"course": "Chemistry", "hours": 60}]}    
];
```

if the length of myArr is more than 2 or less than 10, need return myArr unchanged, but if it more than 10 then need to return last 15 objects of array.

I wrote function, but array returns empty.

```js
export const slicedData = (schedule:Schedule[], name:string) =>
{
  const result:Schedule[] = [];
  result.push({name, schedule});

  if(result.length>=2 && result.length<=10){
     return result;
  }

  return result.slice(-9);
}
```

please advise what i am missing?

Comment: "if the length of myArr is more than 2 or less than 10"... well, that would be every single number possible

Comment: Result is always an array with only one value. You create it in the first line and then push only once.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76375001/return-last-10-objects-of-array-in-typescript#comment134676080_76375001) @freefaller I’m almost certain the asker meant inclusive AND (condition intersection).

Comment: yes it AND condition

Comment: Your function doesn't check the length of myArr, it checks the length of result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@jsejcksn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438273/jsejcksn) wrote in comment, you should use AND (&&) operator instead of OR (||). This guarantee that the value is between 2 and 10.

Again, as [@Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2519416/martijn) noticed, you are creating an array with just one value. If you already have `myArr` you should pass it to function and use it.

```
export const sliceData = (dataToSlice: []) =>
{

  if(dataToSlice.length>=2 && dataToSlice.length<=10){
     return dataToSlice; // return schedule unchanged
  }
  
  // Otherwise return last 10 element of schedule
  return dataToSlice.slice(-10);
}
```

If you don't have the array, is a good idea to create a function that first create your desired array and the call `sliceData`.

A little improvement could be to pass the number of last elements to return:

```
export const sliceData = (dataToSlice: Schedule[], fromLastElement: number) =>
{

  if(dataToSlice.length>=2 && dataToSlice.length<=10){
     return schedule; // return schedule unchanged
  }
  
  // Otherwise return last n elements of schedule
  return dataToSlice.slice(-fromLastElement);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is you are pushing a single object into the `result` and waiting for whole `myArr` to be returned. Also you are checking the `result.length` instead of the `myArr` length when comes to pushing. And if you want to have the last 15 objects of array you need to use `-15` instead of `-9` . With these changes code should be like below.

```
export const slicedData = (myArr:any[]) =>
{
  if(myArr.length>=2 && myArr.length<=10){
     return myArr;
  }

  return result.slice(-15);
}
```